# How to properly design this part of a database (circular reference?)

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, circular-reference, datamodel

**Situation:**

> A company has many projects
>   A project has many tags
>   A project belongs to only 1 company
>   A tag can belong to multiple projects
>   A company must have access to its own tags

Example 1:

[image]

In the first image, all tags for the company are available through the projects/project_tag. But if all projects are removed, then the tags for the company will not be accessible anymore, because the link between project_tag and projects is gone.
The tags should be somehow always be linked to the company, even if there are no projects.

Example 2 (where tags are also linked to the company):

[image]

In the second image, it should work, but is this now a 'circular reference' ???
What should be the best solution for a problem like this?
And what about foreign keys?

The **question** finally is:
**How to properly set up a database/datamodel for this situation?**

---

Example when things could go wrong in the second example:

```
companies:
id=1, name=MyCompany
id=2, name=OtherCompany

tags:
id=1, company_id=1, name=MyTag
id=2, company_id=2, name=OtherTag

projects:
id=1, company_id=1, name=MyProject

project_tag:
project_id=1, tag_id=1
project_id=1, tag_id=2 --> THIS ROW IS NOT VALID!
```

> The last project_tag row is not valid because:
>   **project 1** is linked to **company_id 1**
>   **tag_id 2** is linked to **company_id 2**

---

***UPDATED:*** Thanks all for the information!

Based on the accepted answer, the CREATE queries for PostgreSQL would become:

```
CREATE TABLE companies (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   name TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE projects (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   company_id INT NOT NULL,
   name TEXT NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE (id, company_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES companies (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE tags (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   company_id INT NOT NULL,
   name TEXT NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE (id, company_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES companies (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE project_tag (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   company_id INT NOT NULL,
   project_id INT NOT NULL,
   tag_id INT NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE (company_id, project_id, tag_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (company_id, project_id) REFERENCES projects (company_id, id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY (company_id, tag_id) REFERENCES tags (company_id, id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

> **Tested:**
>   - Rows inserted in project_tag are checked on the **same company_id** (else:
>    denied)
>   - Not possible to insert **duplicate** rows into project_tag
>   - If a project is removed, the linked **project_tag rows** are also removed
>   - If a tag is removed, the linked **project_tag rows** are also removed
>   - If a company is being removed while still having projects, the removal is rejected (see projects table: ON DELETE RESTRICT)
>   - If a company (without projects) is removed, all linked tags are removed also

Comment: There is nothing wrong with "circular references". Please explain what you think one is and why you think there is a problem with them. Your question is predicated on misconceptions. Also, cardinalities are not enough to design by. You must give the meanings of the relation(ship)s/associations of interest--each represented by a table/relation. ("Has", "belongs to" & "linked to" are hopelessly general.) Then given what situations can arise find constraints--cardinalities reflect some of them. Read an intro to info modeling & relational DB design including normalization to higher NFs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relational database design - "cyclic" graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546045/relational-database-design-cyclic-graphs)

Comment: [How do I know which is the more appropriate database design?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46869845/3404097)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your second model is absolutely correct and there is not any circular reference in it.

You should transmit `Company_ID` of `Company` as **F.K** to `Tags` and `Project` and make it **Not Null**.

Then, you should transmit `TAG_ID` and `Project_ID` as **F.K**s into `Project_Tag` and make the unique together. And there is no need to transmit the `Company_ID` of `Project` and `Tag` (that we transmitted in previous paragraph) into `Project_Tag`.

Now, how about final question, Your final request:

> THIS ROW IS NOT VALID!

You **can not capture it by ER**. You should write some functions, triggers or stored procedures to capture and control it.

**Edit**:
Based on @reaanb's comments and his great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413488/how-do-i-ensure-integrity-between-unrelated-tables/43416765#43416765): You can control this constraint by this way with a little redundancy:

```
CREATE TABLE Project(
    project_id INT NOT NULL,
    company_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (project_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES Company (id),
    UNIQUE KEY (project_id, company_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Tag(
    tag_id INT NOT NULL,
    company_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (tag_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES Company (id),
    UNIQUE KEY (tag_id, company_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Project_Tags(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    company_id INT NOT NULL,
    project_id INT NOT NULL,
    tag_id INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY (tag_id, project_id)

    FOREIGN KEY (project_id, company_id) REFERENCES Project (project_id, company_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (tag_id, company_id) REFERENCES Tag (tag_id, company_id),
);
```

Comment: The final request can indeed be handled via FK constraints. See my answers to [How do I ensure integrity between unrelated tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413488/how-do-i-ensure-integrity-between-unrelated-tables/43416765#43416765) and [How to apply complex constraints to a database table in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571843/how-to-apply-complex-constraints-to-a-database-table-in-mysql/42593347#42593347)

Comment: @reaanb, that is not ER and Database Design, you used some **Triggers**.

Comment: Look again. I provided triggers as an alternative, but the first part of each answer shows how to do it using FK constraints only.

Comment: As for not being ER, I agree. The technique depends on superkeys which have no representation in Chen's notation.