# how to solve this database circular dependency

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm creating this simple database which has some sort of tasks created by a company and assigned them to employees.

```
company has many employees
company has many tasks
employees have many tasks
```

In the end, I see all the four tables are in a circle. I'm not sure whether it is good or not. How can I avoid this?

[image]

Comment: it is good. you can database design like this

Comment: Do you really need to have companies directly owning tasks?  If you remove that relationship, things would get simpler (I think).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If I need to query taks by company, then I need a reference

Comment: Well no, employees work for companies so you can always drill up from tasks to employees to company or drill down from company to employee to tasks.

Comment: There is **not** any **circular reference** in this design. You will have a little complex constraints in your tables. see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48110680/6390798). It is so similar to your question.

Comment: `employee_tasks` references `employees` and `tasks`. `employees` and `tasks` reference `company`. `company` doesn't reference anything. Where is the circle?

Comment: Companies don't have tasks. They have employees that have tasks

Comment: Your explanation does _not_ have any "many:many" relationships.  But one of your tables _is_ many:many.  Please rectify the inconsistency.